# Can I run my 3.5" TFT backlight off of a 3.3V supply?

Tags: resistors, lcd, display, touchscreen, tft

I just wanted to confirm my thoughts on the selection of resistor value for a 3.5" TFT screen I am working with.

[image: Backlight circuit diagram]

The datasheet gives a forward voltage of 3.2 V and a forward current of 120 mA.

So if I am correct, when powered by a 3.2 V supply, do I not need to use a resistor? As (3.2V-3.2V)/0.12A = 0 ohms. Or should I just use a very small resistor?

Are there any disadvantages/issues with having the same supply voltage as the forward voltage?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What’s the max guaranteed Vf of your LEDs? What’s the lowest guaranteed output voltage from your power supply?

Comment: The max Vf of the LEDs are 3.5V and the lowest output of the AP2112 LDO i am using is 3.25V.

Comment: Then you need negative resistance. Won’t work. Consider buck-boost converter or a 5 V supply.

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case as I typed that reply! I am currently using a lipo battery and a LDO to power an esp32 and a few sensors. If I wanted to also supply the backlight off of the lipo do you think it would be best to boost the voltage coming off of the battery to 5v to supply the backlight and then use an LDO to drop the 5 volts down to 3.3v? or would there be a better arrangement?

Comment: @henryv3 Linear regulators waste power, always. Don't use them if you can avoid it.

Comment: Would you be able to recommend a better setup for how to get the 3.3v and 5v off of the LiPo? Thanks!

Comment: A LED driver capable of using LiPo voltage range as input and driving the LED with maybe constant current and capable of your LED voltage range. Maybe buck/boost but also less efficient capacitive charge pumps may exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any disadvantages/issues with having the same supply voltage as the forward voltage?

Placing a voltage source across an LED is a bad idea.

LEDs are a current operated device. The brighness is determined directly by the current through the device. The forward voltage is a consequence of the colour of the emitted light and diode action.

The ideal power supply for an LED is a constant current source. This allows the diode voltage to fluctuate from diode to diode and for temperature changes. The resistor used in series with the LED and a voltage source is an attempt to create a non-ideal constant current source. It works well as long as the resistor is not too small because forward voltage fluctuations cause large changes in current.

The situation is not the best for battery consumption. Too high a voltage for the LED resistor string wastes power in the resistor.

I would use a buck-boost converter to between 4 and 5 volts to drive the LEDs. If 5V, then a boost may be sufficient.

I would then choose either an LDO to regulate the buck-boosted voltage down to the microcontroller voltage. OR use a second buck boost to provide the 3.3V.

There are several design choices and tradeoffs that I leave to you.